# Using C4.5 classifier with multiple outcomes

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking at C4.5 classifier for a machine learning task.  I have a large dataset containing city names, and need to differentiate between e.g.  London Ontario, London England or even London in Burgundy in France, but looking at features from the surrounding text:  E.g. Zip codes, state names, even when "Canada" or "England" are not mentioned.  I also have access to meta data such as dialing codes which can help determine which country it is.

Subsequently once trained I want to run the classifier on the large dataset.

In all the examples I have found [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/dtrees/c4.5/c4.5_prob1.html) there are only 2 states for the result (in this golf example play or don't play).

Can the c4.5 classifier handle London (Canada), London (England), London (France) as result classes or do I need to have different classifiers for London (Canada) True/False etc?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options in your case.

- The first approach is a straightforward extension to c4.5. In each leaf node, you keep all the labels instead of just the majority label. For example, as shown in the figure below, red labels actually present in three different leafs. When you have a query at the data point pointed by the arrow, the outputs are 3 labels (green, red and blue) together with their corresponding conditional probability `p(c|v)` (given feature `x1` and `x2`, what is the probability of data `x` belongs to class `c`).

[image: single tree classification]

- The 2nd approach is to generate multiple decision trees hence a random forest. The randomness can be injected by randomly sampling subset of training data made available to each individual tree. At classification time, you can aggregate the vote from all decision trees to get multi-class classification results.

[image: random forest ensemble]

The figures are borrowed from this excellent [tutorial](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect5.pdf) on multi-class classification by Andrew Zisserma.